# Building up an Economic Scenario Generator

Tags: interest-rates, stochastic-calculus, simulations

I am trying to build an Economic Scenario Generator in VBA or Python. Can anyone please help me with some good resources which I can follow or some basic procedures which explains how to go about in building it.
Thank you .